# Put image in div element and keep image ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML :**

```
<div id="presentationViewContainer">
    <img id="presentationView" />
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#presentationViewContainer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 530px;
  top: 106px;
  left: 28px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgb(75, 80, 86);
}

#presentationView {
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

**Actual result if image is in portrait mode:** : Image height is so big..

[image]

**Expected result if image is in portrait mode :** image should be on red square to see the entire image :

[image]

**Actual result if image is in landscape :** image should be centered :

[image]

**Expected result if image is in landscape mode :** image should be centered :

[image]

**JSFIDDLE :**

For portrait mode : https://jsfiddle.net/8e1p351u/
For landscape mode : https://jsfiddle.net/n9b8q82o/

UPDATE :

Here is the actual result now :

How can i do to set the position of the image in the red square ?

[image]

Comment: Whats the question? or did i just not see one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set a height to the container.

Updated Fiddles : [Portrait](https://jsfiddle.net/8e1p351u/3/) - [Landscape](https://jsfiddle.net/n9b8q82o/2/)

```css
#presentationViewContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 530px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  height: 100%;
    border: blue dashed 1px;
}

#presentationView {
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgb(75, 80, 86);
}
img{
  border : red solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="presentationViewContainer">
 <img id="presentationView" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Tour_Eiffel_3c02660.jpg" />
</div>
```

Also, here are three of my **experiments about image magic centering with no stretch** :

[With regular CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/1q5brovo/1/)

[With object-fit : contain](http://jsfiddle.net/8q1s8vrL/1/) (not supported by any version of IE)

[With Flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/z4rcumz9/2/)

Comment: I tested your code. Please see my update in the post. The image is good but the position is not good (on the top left corner). I would like to set the position on red square.. Could you help me ?

Comment: Did you click my last two links? The magic centering experiments?

Comment: Edit : last three links, since Vandervals made me discover object-fit:contain

Comment: Do you know, how i can add a border around the img ? (Which stay around the img)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I can't make it too easy for you. If you google that, you will find it in 3 seconds ;)

Comment: If you talk about to add this line `border : 1px solid blue` it doesn't work.

Comment: Why yes it does. I have updated my example above and added a red border.

Comment: Oooops sorry my bad, I reverted my edit. It works now.

Comment: I use object-fit:contain option in my code. I created this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eh759oLo/  You can see that the img border is not set around the image. How can i do that by using object-contain property?

Comment: Ah, that's different. object-fit is new to me, and I noticed that it behaves in a weird way : the image gets sort of _resized inside itself_... So the border IS actually around the image, but the pixels are drawn differently _inside_ the image itself... Very disturbing indeed. If you want a border around the image, you will have to use another method than object-fit.

Answer (score 3):

With css3 new rules this is very easy:

```
.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@supports(object-fit: cover){
    .container img{
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center center;
    }
}
```

If you are concern about old browsers flexbox won't help you nor the translate method in many cases. If this is very important for you, you can give dimensions to your image and do this:

```
.container img{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -200px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

Comment: Do you know, how i can add a border around the img ? (Which stay around the img)

Comment: @wawanopoulos did you try border or border-image?

Answer (score 2):

You can ditch your container and do it like this:

Edit:
This should work for both landscape and portrait and is responsive. Basically it works for any container. In this case the container is just body with 100% height & width. Don't forget your css resets!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#presentationView {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img id="presentationView" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Tour_Eiffel_3c02660.jpg" />
```

Comment: or maybe just use flex?

Comment: what about browser support?

Comment: From your code's perspective, what about IE? :P **transform**

Comment: support for transform is IE9 - for flex it's IE10
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex